# How to open a external url in a dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular v14 and attempting to open an external website using mat-dialog in my application.

I tried this code in my dialog.component.html

```
<iframe [src]="'https://www.saucedemo.com/v1/'" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

but the modal is show as blank.

How can I solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have two `width` parameters, which one is correct? Also, check the console for potential errors, not all websites agree to be displayed in iframes.